# How far apart should I space Jerusalem artichokes?

Tags: sunchoke, spacing

How much room does a single Jerusalem artichoke (AKA sunroot, AKA sunchoke) plant need, given plenty of sun and a semi-arid climate?

I've grown some wild seedlings (from true seeds from Kansas Native Plants), which I just transplanted fairly close, but I plan to split up some tubers a traditional distance when they're mature enough (probably next spring). So, I'll need to know how far to space them.

The seedlings are looking pretty good. I grew lots of them for plenty of genetic diversity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [RHS](https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/grow-your-own/vegetables/jerusalem-artichoke) says one foot but of course after the first season they'll sprout anywhere depending on what's been left behind. If you plant them too far apart the wind can blow them down so I found it's easier to keep them closer together so that they can be supported.